# PS file from Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, ps

I create a document in overleaf and i need to have PDF, DVI and PS formats of thet document. PDF got, for DVI I had to change compiler to LaTeX, but I do not see PS file there.
How can I get that format? All my graphics are in .eps format.

[image: other logs and files]

Comment: are you _sure_ you need those formats? It sounds like the requirements were written in the 1980s.... but you can use latexmk to set up a latex->dvi->ps->pdf pipeline using latex dvips and ps2pdf as the executables for each stage then you will have the output in all three forms.

Comment: yes, that answers my question. i didnt know "latexmkrc file" is just "latexmkrc" without any format (like .tex, .exe, etc.). Thanks!